# How did Royden prove the surjectiveness of the function mapping $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb N$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I was reading *Countable and uncountable Sets* from *Royden*'s *Real Analysis*; here he discusses that Cartesian product and set of Rational numbers $\mathbb  Q$ is countably infinite:

[image]

For the first one, he showed that $g: \mathbb N\times \mathbb N\mapsto \mathbb N$ is injective by showing $g(m,n) = g(m^\prime, n^\prime)\implies m= m^\prime;~ n= n^\prime \,.$ This is clear form the discussion.

But after showing the one-to-one ness, he concluded $g$ is bijective. Why did he not show the surjectiveness of $g$? Or did I miss some of his wordings that implicitly conclude $g$ is onto?

He did this in the second one too (okay *left it as an exercise*); he told that $g$ is one to one and just in the immediate sentence, he concluded $g:\mathbb Q\mapsto N; N\subset\mathbb N$ is equipotent i.e., bijective; why? How did he conclude it is also surjective?

Comment: Perhaps look at the preceding theorem(s)? It seems to boil down to that.

Comment: Which theorem @Camille? Earlier in the page he proved there exists a bijection between a subset of $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N\,.$

Comment: If $g$ maps $\mathbb{Q}$ injectively to a subset $N$ of $\mathbb{N}$, then the map $g:\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow R_g$ from $\mathbb{Q}$ to the range of $g$ is surjective by definition. So it is bijective. We can set $N = R_g$. Then there exists a bijective map $f:N\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, so $f\circ g$ is bijective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you seem to be missing or misunderstanding is this part of the proof:

> Therefore $\mathbf N\times\mathbf N$ is equipotent to $g(\mathbf N\times\mathbf N)$, a subset of the countable set $\mathbf N$. We infer from the preceding theorem that $\mathbf N\times\mathbf N$ is countable.

It is not entirely clear what "the preceding theorem" is, but I would guess it is something like "an infinite subset of a countable set is countable".

Note that the proof does *not* claim that $g$ is surjective onto $\mathbb N$, only that (as any function) it is surjective onto its *range* $g(\mathbb N\times\mathbb N)$, and this range is some subset of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Some *infinite* subset.